# CORS Error while trying to fetch data from Upwork api

Tags: upwork-api

I am getting cors error on all the APIs of Upwork. I am using a react application. Below is one of the api

```
axios.get('https://www.upwork.com/api/profiles/v2/search/jobs.json',{
    headers: {
        Authorization': `Bearer token`,
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    }
})
```

[image: error from the console]

Answer (score 0):

CORS requests are prohibited for security reasons.